# How to optimize the load of many data options into a select box using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm selecting product name and code from the database and populating into dropdown and I have more than 40000 products in DB when clicking the dropdown it's very slow to open and sometimes it's not opening. Please help how to solve this issue.

**Controler**

```
public function create()
{
  $arr["product"] = product::where('prod_flag', 1)->pluck('prod_product_code', 'product_name');
        

        return view('backend.product_category.create')->with($arr);
}
```

**View Blade File**

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product</label>
        <select class="form-control select2" id="catpro_prod_code" name="catpro_prod_code">
             <option>Select Product</option>
                @foreach($product as $prodName => $prodCode)
                     <option value="{{$prodCode}}">{{$prodName}}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: Setting so many options in html will always be a problem you will simply have to limit the amount of data for that one or have to make an clever javascript solution that searches for the option you want and limits it like so.

Comment: So a better solution is populate the data with javascript

Comment: A better solution is to make search functionality in javascript and populate the options with a smaller amount of data. 40k rows is probably gonna go slow no matter what.

Comment: Since you seem to be using `select2` ... it already has the ability to use a remote data source: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: Please, when it is possible, give an answer to the above question. Possibly, take the comment and make it as an answer. Then make the answer as accepted/useful. It helps others that have similar/same problem too.